# ¿Cómo encriptar script de archivo .vbs?

Tags: vbscript

Estoy probando esto de crear scripts en VBS y leí en un lado que se pueden encriptar los códigos que tu hagas para que cuando alguien más lo abra (el archivo) no verá el código, pero si se ejecutará el script normalmente.

Leí también que era con un programa de encrypt, pero dicen que ya no se descarga de la página de Microsoft sino que viene embebido ahora con la instalación del windows.

Con el programa se supone que se encripta usando la sentencia

```
screnc <fichero.vbs> <fichero.vbe>
```

desde `cmd` y esto generaba otro archivo con el script encriptado...

Estuve buscando y me decían que usara el siguiente código:

```
Set encode = CreateObject("Scripting.Encoder")
encode asd.vbs aaaa.vbe
```

Pero no funciona, sale el siguiente error:

```
Secuencia de comandos: [Aquí dice pues la ruta de mi archivo .vbs que quiero ejecutar]
Línea: 2
Carácter: 16
Error: Se esperaba instrucción final de instrucción
Código: 800A0401
Origen: Error de compilación de Microsoft VBScript
```

Y ya, no hace nada :/

---

---

Adicional *(Solo si alguien sabe)* quisiera saber cómo cambiar el icono que aparece en la ventana de un dialog que genero:

[image: Imagen_1]

U ocultarlo no sé; Este aparece solo cuando uso la sentencia `vbSystemModal` en la creación del Msgbox, el código que uso para generar el dialog es esté:

```
Acepta = Msgbox(Mensaje, vbYesNo+vbQuestion+vbSystemModal, Titulo)
```

Y no sé si se podrá cambiar este icono también, información sobre eso si no he encontrado.

[image: Imagen_2]

Comment: Es mejor hacer dos preguntas por separado, que meter dos en un mismo "post".

Comment: Puedes poner un bucle for y poner una InputBox que te pida la contraseña. Mientras la variable establecida en el Input sea distinta a la variable que contiene la contraseña, se repite for

Comment: Esto es solo seguro si el usuario no es programador de vbs. Se puede editar fácilmente si se tiene noción sobre lo que se hace

Comment: Quizas lo que debas utilizar es el [VbsEdit](http://www.vbsedit.com/), permite la "Compilación" con icono y nivel de autenticacion necesario, less no te cambia el icono del modal. Ademas deja hacerlo gratuitamente.

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo tu problema. Al usar *screnc* se genera un archivo *.vbe*, que es el archivo original, pero ofuscado.

Para ejecutarlo, lo hace de la misma manera que con un *vbs* normal.

Por curiosidad, ¿para que necesitas cifrar tu script y ocultar los iconos?

Comment: Parece que funciona lo del encriptar jaja, seguridad del código, no ocultarlo, sino para que el usuario (alguien que sepa algo de vbs) no pueda modificar el código para saltarse unas validaciones esenciales para la correcta ejecución

Comment: No es ocultar los iconos, en realidad es mostrarlo jaja, no sé cómo hacer para que se muestre un icono y no el simbolos de programas de windows

Comment: @FabianMontoya Alguien que sepa de código va a poder des-ofuscar el script en 5 minutos. Mejor establecer un sistema de validación más seguro.

Answer (score -1):

Pues aprovechamos el propio ofuscador/desofuscador de windows, que usa para el html., asignamos y creamos el objeto, leemos el archivo completo lo tratamos y guardamos stream en otro archivo. El detalle interesante es que de entrada no se permite hacerlo con archivos hta, por eso se expecifica que los trate como htm. y asi funciona como un archivo para IE. el ejemplo solo se tiene que guardar como vbs, y sustituir los archivos por los que nos interesen.

```vbs
    Option Explicit 
  
    dim oEncoder, oFSO
        set oEncoder = CreateObject("Scripting.Encoder") 
        set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

    dim oFile, oStream, sSourceFile 'archivo a ofuscar
        'set oFile = oFSO.GetFile("leeregistro.vbs") 
        set oFile = oFSO.GetFile("Untitled.hta") 
        Set oStream = oFile.OpenAsTextStream(1) 
            sSourceFile=oStream.ReadAll 
        oStream.Close 
    
    dim oEncFile, sDest 'Archivo de salida
        'Set oEncFile = oFSO.CreateTextFile("leeregistro.vbe") 
        Set oEncFile = oFSO.CreateTextFile("Untitled_en.hta") 
        'EncFile.Write oEncoder.EncodeScriptFile(".vbs", sSourceFile, 0, "VBScript") 
        oEncFile.Write oEncoder.EncodeScriptFile(".htm", sSourceFile, 0, "VBScript") ' poner .htm para archivos .hta 
            ' Extension: ".vbs", ".js", ".htm", ".html"
        oEncFile.Close
```

En cuanto a la segunda pregunta, la del icono, la solución es poner su codigo en una aplicación hta, y podra hacer eso y mucho mas, todo lo que le permita IE. Existe bastante información sobre aplicaciones hta en la red.

Comment: "Estoy probando esto de crear scripts en VBS y leí en un lado que se pueden encriptar los códigos que tu hagas para que cuando alguien más lo abra (el archivo) no verá el código, pero si se ejecutará el script normalmente. "Esta es la pregunta, y la respuesta es 100% efectiva.